# add items from access to combobox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I want to fill a combobox with items from ms access database.
here's my code..

```
conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ainunandile\Desktop\ElectionDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
conn.Open()
sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM Candidates where Position='President'"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, conn)
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While rdr.Read()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(rdr("CandidateName").ToString())
End While
```

however the combobox won't fill up, but if i remove the "where Position ='President'" the code works, can someone help me i've been stuck here for hours.

Comment: sounds like there are no rows matching the query. check spelling as well

Comment: @Plutonix i've checked already. spelling's the same for Position and President from the db. I rewrote it just in case but still not working.

Comment: Your mdb is on your desktop?  It doesn't belong there.  Put a debug break on your while loop, see if it enters the loop.  If it doesn't, you have no records.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this i hope this work.

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ainunandile\Desktop\ElectionDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
       Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          cn.Open()
          Dim cm As New OleDbCommand("select * from Candidates where Position='President'", cn)
          Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
          While dr.Read
             ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr(1).ToString)
          End While
          dr.Close()
          cn.Close()
       End Sub
```